# UISearchBar in Navigation Bar cannot enter text

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I'm having a weird problem, when my app first loads you cannot enter text in the search bar no matter how many times you tap it, the search bar is nested in the navigation bar.

My app also use a tab bar, and when you switch tabs then go back to the tab with the search bar it allows you enter text... any ideas what's causing this?

Heres the code for the searchBar:

```
func setupSearchBar(){

    let locationSearchTable = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LocationSearchTable") as! LocationSearchTableViewController
    resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchTable)
    resultSearchController?.searchResultsUpdater = locationSearchTable

    searchBar = resultSearchController!.searchBar
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.placeholder = "Location"
    searchBar.isTranslucent = true
    searchBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    for subView in searchBar.subviews{

        for subsubView in subView.subviews{

            if let textField = subsubView as? UITextField{

                var currentTextFieldBounds = textField.bounds
                currentTextFieldBounds.size.height = 40.0
                textField.bounds = currentTextFieldBounds
                textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.none
                textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
                textField.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 25.0)
                textField.textColor = theme?.textColour

            }
        }
    }

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBarColour(colour: (theme?.tabBarColour)!, tint: (theme?.textColour)!)

    navigationItem.titleView = resultSearchController?.searchBar
    navigationItem.titleView?.bringSubview(toFront: (resultSearchController?.searchBar)!)
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.showsSearchResultsButton = true
    searchBar.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "location_icon.png"), for: UISearchBarIcon.resultsList, state: UIControlState.normal)

    resultSearchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    resultSearchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    definesPresentationContext = true

    locationSearchTable.mapView = mapView
    locationSearchTable.handleMapSearchDelegate = self

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot enter text", the keyboard was not showing or you cannot type anything into the textbox?

Comment: Keyboard won't show at all. Only after you've changed tabs. I'll post some code in a bit, I'm currently out of the house at the moment.

Comment: Plz add screenshots & more info...without hard to find the issue

Comment: Screen shot won't help, you tap on search bar to enter text and nothing happens. I've tried isUserInteractionEnabled, zPositions and layoutsubviews etc nothing works.

Comment: have you tried it on a real iPhone? Because the simulator will sometimes not show a keyboard when it should

Comment: Yeah tried on iPhone & iPad, no change.

Comment: Ive now updated the question and included some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after a lot messing around, I discovered that in my custom UITabBarController I had used `override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)` without adding `super.viewWillAppear()` and that caused the problem! I assume because of that subviews weren't being laid out correctly. Hope that helps anyone who has a similar problem to mine.